# How to use prepared statement on materialized view in python Cassandra driver?

Tags: python, scylla, cassandra-python-driver

i am using Scylla Database  and python Cassandra driver for my project, i used prepared statement on every query and it works, but  when i use prepared statement on materialized view, it returns me nothing, can you please help me, is there any restriction or something else?

here is my schema

```
CREATE TABLE channelfollowers(
channelid bigint,
userid bigint,
isfavorite boolean,
isBlocked boolean,
followDate bigint,
PRIMARY KEY(userid,channelid,followDate));
```

`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW favoriteChannels
AS SELECT channelid, userid, isfavorite
FROM channels.channelfollowers 
WHERE channelid IS NOT NULL  and userid IS NOT NULL  and isfavorite IS NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (isfavorite,userid,channelid,followDate);`

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you don't provide any code?

Comment: let me provide you

Comment: i have updated my question kindly review it 

thanks

Comment: Please post not only your Schema but the python code you use, so we can review it.

Answer (score 2):

Materialized Views in Scylla are still experimental, so some caveats apply. Are you querying data that you inserted before creating the materialized view? If so, then currentely that data isn't propagated to the view.